# Speeding up the time of integration calculation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I am going to integrate from Chebyshev orthogonal functions that is in the form of:

```
  u1[i_, j_] = (1 + 2*x/a)*(1 - 2*x/a)*(1 + 2*y/b)*(1 - 2*y/b)*
  Cos[(i - 1)*ArcCos[2*x/a - 1]]*Cos[(j - 1)*ArcCos[2*y/b - 1]];
 u2[K_, P_] = Sum[u1[i, j]^2, {i, K}, {j, P}];
```

Where I and j are in the range of 1 to 100.
Because i*j=10^4, ten thousand integrations should be computed, so, it is very important to speed up the integrations.

The integration time is very long especially when the amount of i and j increase. For example, when i and j are from 1 to 5, we have

```
    a = 0.5;
    b = 0.7;
    n = 5;
    z = 5;
    
  Table[NIntegrate[u2[K, P], {x, 0, a}, {y, 0, b}], {K, 1, n}, {P, 1, 
  z}] // Timing
```

The result is=

```
  {154.063, {{0.822889, 1.32889, 1.59296, 1.95275, 2.33988}, {1.32889, 
  2.14603, 2.57249, 3.15352, 3.77868}, {1.59296, 2.57249, 3.08369, 
  3.78018, 4.52957}, {1.95275, 3.15352, 3.78018, 4.63398, 
  5.55264}, {2.33988, 3.77868, 4.52957, 5.55264, 6.65341}}}
```

The elapsed time is 154 second and during the computations. My computer is old, maybe in another computer, fewer time is displayed.

you see when i and j are from 1 to 5, the elapsed time is too long, Now consider how long it will take if the i and j are from 1 to 100.
Any suggestion for speeding up the integrations will be very appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Look up `NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis/ref/GaussianQuadratureWeights` in the help. Or on the web: `https://reference.wolfram.com/language/NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis/ref/GaussianQuadratureWeights.html`

Comment: You might separate the x and y part of the intergration

Comment: In your modified code you define scalar `u=...` but later use array `u[k,p]` ???

Comment: Sorry, I corrected it.

Comment: Your "modification" gives a new question. The original content, my answer is related to, cannot be seen anymore

Answer (score 4):

The integral  you are looking for might be separated into x-part  and y-part.
Additionally introducing new variables `\[Xi]=x/a, \[Eta]=y/b` gives the following expression for the integral

`a b  Integrate[(1 -(2 \[Xi])^2) Cos[(i - 1) ArcCos[2 \[Xi] - 1]], {\[Xi], 0, 1}]*Integrate[(1 -(2 \[Eta]) ^2) Cos[(i - 1) ArcCos[2 \[Eta] - 1]], {\[Eta], 0, 1}]`

It's only necessary to evaluate one part

```
int=Table[NIntegrate[(1 -(2 \[Xi])^2) Cos[(i - 1) ArcCos[2 \[Xi] - 1]], {\[Xi], 0, 1},Method -> "LocalAdaptive"],{i,1,1000}]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

Evaluation only spents  `20s` for 1000x1000 integrals!

The Matrix of integrals `i,j` follow to

```
intij=a b Outer[Times ,int,int];
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Dear Ulrich Neumann, Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, I cannot separate the integration into x- and y- parts manually. because, I am doing some Algebric manipulation on the original function (like multiplying, power  etc. )  and the result should be integrated. 1- Is there any command that separate into x- and y- parts? 2- With these conditions, how should we change your suggested code? Thank you.

Comment: @PooyaAzizi You should modify your question. Only multiplying or power operations keep the possibilty of separation I think.

Comment: You are right. I apologize. Could you please help with this conditions?

Comment: Please show the modified integrand!

Comment: I reviewed and corrected the post

Comment: For the modified question you only have to change `int` to `int = Table[
   NIntegrate[((1 - (2 \[Xi])^2) Cos[(i - 1) ArcCos[
          2 \[Xi] - 1]])^2, {\[Xi], 0, 1}, 
    Method -> "LocalAdaptive"], {i, 1, 1000}];`

Answer (score 3):

Combining @UlrichNeumann's solution with analytic integration we get instantaneous results (0.6 seconds for 1000×1000 integrals) that remain accurate for very large $i$ and $j$:

```
g[i_?EvenQ] = 2/((i + 1) (i - 3));
g[i_?OddQ] = (i^2 - 2 i - 2)/((i + 2) i (i - 2) (i - 4));

a = 0.5;
b = 0.7;
G = Table[g[i], {i, 0, 10}];
intij = a * b * KroneckerProduct[G, G]

(*    {{0.155556, 0.0777778, 0.155556, 0.0155556, -0.0933333, -0.0288889, -0.0222222, -0.00814815, -0.0103704, -0.00410774, -0.00606061},
       {0.0777778, 0.0388889, 0.0777778, 0.00777778, -0.0466667, -0.0144444, -0.0111111, -0.00407407, -0.00518519, -0.00205387, -0.0030303},
       ...
       {-0.00606061, -0.0030303, -0.00606061, -0.000606061, 0.00363636, 0.00112554, 0.000865801, 0.00031746, 0.00040404, 0.000160042, 0.000236128}}    *)
```

Comment: Dear roman, Thank you very much for your answer. because my function I integrate in not exactly the mentioned function, I change the post because the function couldn't separate to x- and y- parts. please see the function again and suggest your opinion. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

How about ParallelTable?

```
ParallelTable[NIntegrate[u2[K, P], {x, 0, a}, {y, 0, b}], {K, 1, n}, {P, 1, z}] // Timing
```